# Проблема с кириллической кодировкой FPDF

Tags: php, кодировка, кириллица, fpdf

Вопрос:
Как подружить плагин FPDF с кириллицей?
Стоит FPDF 1.8
1) генерирую файлы Arial и TimesNewRoman встроенной утилитой makefont

```
require("makefont/makefont.php");   
MakeFont("font/test/arial.ttf","cp1251");  
MakeFont("font/test/times.ttf","cp1251");
```

2) Далее обращаюсь к файлам для формирования pdf

```
define('FPDF_FONTPATH','fpdf/font/test/'); 
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');   
$pdf=new FPDF('P');
$pdf->AddFont('ArialMT','','arial.php');
$pdf->AddFont('TimesNRCyrMT','','times.php');
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('ArialMT','',11);
$pdf->Cell(37,4,'РУССКИЙ ТЕКСТ' ,0,0,'L',0);
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->SetFont('TimesNRCyrMT','',11);
$pdf->Cell(37,4,'РУССКИЙ ТЕКСТ' ,0,0,'L',0);
$pdf->Ln();  
ob_start(); 
$pdf->Output();
```

При запуске скрипта PDF выдаёт что-то подобное в PDF файле

```
Р РЈРЎРЎРљРР™ РўР•РљРЎРў
Р РЈРЎРЎРљРР™ РўР•РљРЎРў
```

Пробывал менять шрифты, брал их из разных источников ..

Также формировал шрифты с помощью [этого сайта](http://www.fpdf.org/makefont/index.php). Тщетно.

Запросы на сервер уходят с кодировкой UTF-8 как и сами файлы *.php
Может в этом проблема?

Пробывал

```
header("content-type:text/html; charset=cp1251");
```

Этот способ тоже не помогает.

Comment: Вас не смущает второй аргумент в MakeFont?

Comment: `cp1251` - по-твоему, именно так пишется  utf-8?

Comment: Дело в том что у MakeFont есть только 3 килирических формата для конверта: cp1251,iso-8859-4, koi8-r и в них конверить я тоже пытался. получав всё больше интересных кракозябр

Comment: Спасибо за последний ответ, всю голову сломал за два дня.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нашёл решение, если кто столкнётся с подобным:

```
$text = iconv('utf-8', 'windows-1251', $text);
```