# Русские буквы на fdpf

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

Напишите вес алгоритм как сделать поддержку русских букв на Fpdf на php. Переводил в afm все равно не работает

Comment: возможный дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/713189/223826

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А вот это на `FDPF` сайте читали:

> The class can produce documents in many languages other than the
>   Western European ones: Central European, Cyrillic, Greek, Baltic and
>   Thai, provided you own TrueType or Type1 fonts with the desired
>   character set. UTF-8 support is also available.

Возможно `tFPDF` то что вас интересует. Это FPDF с поддержкой UTF-8
http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script92.php

Comment: Заработало спасибо!!